# Edit conf file linux under specific section

Tags: linux, sed, configuration-files

I have a file that I want to change from command line. The thing is that it has sections and in some different sections it has the same values that I need to change.

The file looks like:

```
...

[DEFAULT]

findtime = 600
maxretry = 3

[ssh]

maxretry = 6
```

And I want to change only the maxretry under [DEFAULT].
Maybe there is a conifuration command line that searches the section in config file and changes value named X ?

The command I wrote with sed changes all occurences and I want only the first occurence after [DEFAULT]

```
sudo sed -i "s/\(^maxretry =.*$\)/maxretry = ${NUMBER_OF_RETRIES}/" filename
```

Appreciate your help.
Thanks

Comment: You can use this sed syntax `sed '0,/pattern/s/pattern/replacement/' filename` to substitute only a first occurrence of string.

Comment: Please, when you're searching for free help from the community - appreciate their time and accept the appropriate answers!

Answer (score 2):

One way using awk:

```
$ NUMBER_OF_RETRIES=5
$ awk '/^\[DEFAULT\]/{f=1;}f && /^maxretry =/{print "maxretry = "x;f=0;next}1' x=$NUMBER_OF_RETRIES file
```

First, we search for the DEFAULT section, and once found, set a flag. Search for the line beginning with maxretry, and if flag is set, do the replacement.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks Guru. I see the change in the output, but how do I change "file" to include the change after I run the command using awk ? Thanks

Comment: You can re-direct the output of this command to a file, and then move it to the original file

Comment: Thanks. Done     sudo awk '/^\[DEFAULT\]/{f=1;}f && /^maxretry =/{print "maxretry = "x;f=0;next}1' x=${NUMBER_OF_RETRIES} /etc/fail2ban/jail.local | sudo tee /etc/fail2ban/jail.local.tmp
    sudo mv /etc/fail2ban/jail.local.tmp /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

Answer (score 0):

You can check a default flag, which tells you if a substitution occurred or not:

```
awk '!f && /^maxretry =.*$/ {$0="maxretry = 666"; f=1} 1'
```

Note that this will not write the change in the file, just redirect the output to a new file or do smth similar. This approach is very specific and works only for first occurrence. @Guru's answer is more generic and can work for arbitrary section (e.g. you want to replace the 2nd,3rd occurrence depending on the section). Nevertheless this example is simpler when targeting the first occurrence.

Comment: Thanks very much hovanessyan. Appreciate your time very much, I used Guru's answer which seems more fit for my project. Thanks again